# mvc entity framework select case when

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, select, case

how can I translate this into LINQ?

```html
Select
 Object =  case when C.Description='UPLOAD' 
            then (select SeekName from Uploads where Upload_id= C.Object_id)
       else case when C.Description='ACTIVITY'
  then (select Name from Activities  where Activity_id= C.Object_id)
  else (select SUBSTRING(Description,1,10) from Questions  where Question_id= C.Object_id)
  end
  end,
From Contact C
```

I know that I case use `let` to replace `case when`. But i need to do a `Select` statement in each `case when`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from c in context.Contact
select new {obj = c.Description == "UPLOAD" ? c.Uploads.SeekName
               :  c.Description == "ACTIVITY" ? c.Activity.Name
                    : c.Question.Description.SubString(1,10)}
```

If you have the FK set up and it's 1-to-1, else you have to modify the selection like `C.Uploads.SeekName` and use some join to find the value